# Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to delete the history Windows 2019

Tags: .net, windows, iis

I have recently deployed a Windows Server 2019 on AWS.  We have installed IIS, and are running a WCF service using .net 4.5.1.  The WCF service is running fine and the server is up to date with regards Windows updates.

However, I noticed that we are getting regular entries in the Windows event viewer of the following:

> The Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to
> delete the history directory
> 'C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000021'.  The directory will be
> skipped and ignored.  Note that the directory may still get deleted in
> the future if the service restarts.  The data field contains the error
> number.

[image: Screenshot of Event Viewer entries]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I have encountered the same error, did you manage to solve this one?